# Magento 2: Override \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart

Tags: magento2

How can we override `Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` class in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override using preference method in di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Cart" />
</config>
```

You have to create Cart class in your module in order to extend Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart. E.g:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model;


class Cart extends \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
{
     //override respective methods
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to modify some methods on this class, first try to use plugins instead of extending whole class.

Comment: Great! How about providing a useful answer that includes details as to how to do so rather than just suggesting something without explaining anything?